# Value to type String cannot be Convert into JsonObject?

Tags: java, android, json

Am making simple login application using volley if user enter the correct login they will get `json` response from server when i tried to parse that `jsonobject` to string am getting value of type string cannot be converted into `jsonobject` how to convert `jsonobject` to string my `json` response will be like this:

```
{"loginResult":"EmployeeCode: 4112 ModuleID:1 ModuleName:XXX UserID:762"}
```

so far what is tried to parse this json object is :

```
 String resp=response.toString();
        try {
            JSONObject yog=new JSONObject(resp);
            String yogs=yog.getString("loginResult");
            String yogan=yog.getString("EmployeeCode");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

as a beginner am really confused to parse this jsonobject into string can anybody explain me how to parese this jsonobject !!!

Comment: I guess the JSON is not proper. There are no differentiation between the elements in your login result.

Comment: then how to parse this

Comment: It is not proper JSON. In back end you need to format response properly otherwise it will not be parsed.

Comment: {"loginResult":"{\"UserLoginID\":864,\"UserID\":864,\"EmployeeCode\":\"PI4264\",‌​\"Password\":\"ÆÍâäàâ\",\"IsPasswordChanged\":false,\"ModuleName\":\"XXX\",\"Modu‌​leID\":1,\"EmployeeName\":\"XXX \"}"} can you tell me how to parse this

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON:

`{
  "loginResult": "EmployeeCode: 4112 ModuleID:1 ModuleName:XXX UserID:762"
}`

so, from this JSON, you can only `jsonObject.getString()` on `loginResult`,the value for this String is=
`EmployeeCode: 4112 ModuleID:1 ModuleName:XXX UserID:762`
so remove `String yogan=yog.getString("EmployeeCode");` from your code.

Comment: i need to get it as separate string in employeecode,modulename,userid

Comment: in that case you do not have a valid JSON, however, you can still work on it using `String.split()`, but try to get the JSON response in this format
`{
  "loginResult": {
    "EmployeeCode": 4112,
    "ModuleID": 1,
    "ModuleName": "XXX",
    "UserID": 762
  }
}`

Comment: now can you tell me how to parse this json to string {"loginResult":" UserID:762"}

Comment: if your response is a string,
`try{
JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(response_string);
String userId=jsonObject.getString("UserID");}`

Comment: {"loginResult":"{\"UserLoginID\":864,\"UserID\":864,\"EmployeeCode\":\"PI4264\",‌​\"Password\":\"ÆÍâäàâ\",\"IsPasswordChanged\":false,\"ModuleName\":\"XXX\",\"Modu‌​leID\":1,\"EmployeeName\":\"XXX \"}"} can you tell me how to parse this

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your json response.Ideally this should be your json.

```
{"loginResult":{"EmployeeCode":4400,"ModuleID":1,"ModuleName":"XXX","UserID":1213}}
```

Try the following

```
JSONObject result=resp.getJSONObject("loginResult");
String empcode=result.getString("EmployeeCode");
```

Comment: {"loginResult":"{\"UserLoginID\":864,\"UserID\":864,\"EmployeeCode\":\"PI4264\",\"Password\":\"ÆÍâäàâ\",\"IsPasswordChanged\":false,\"ModuleName\":\"XXX\",\"ModuleID\":1,\"EmployeeName\":\"XXX  \"}"}  can you tell me how to parse this

Comment: I have already written the logic to parse, once your json is ready in the expected format. You need to make corrections in server response and try from mobile end

Comment: there are lots for backslash when i try to get userid it throw no value for userid

Comment: This is the response that you should get from server. Make sure you get this : {"loginResult":{"EmployeeCode":4400,"ModuleID":1,"ModuleName":"XXX","UserID":1213}} . without this you will get error.

Comment: you should get the response I have mentioned in answer. else it is an error. Use this for validation http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/